# How to add a Word document, at the end of the other, while keeping the added documents margins/header etc?

Tags: microsoft-word

The problem is simple, but there seems to be no way of doing it in Word.

I have two documents I want to merge into one. Ie. add one document to the end of the other.

All google results only shows how to copy text or insert text from document at the end of the document, which is NOT the same. It will not take header/footer/page margin and orientation into account and the document will end up a mess.

So are there really no way of adding a copy of a document at the end of a word document, while keeping the correct header/margins/page orientation etc?

Comment: Have you tried putting a section break between the two?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to insert doc2 at the end of doc1 and keep doc2's margins and headers/footers try the following approach:

1. Insert section break (next page) at the end of doc1.
2. Insert section break (next page) at the beginning of doc2.
3. Insert section break (next page) at the end of doc2.
4. Open doc1. Insert doc2 into doc1 using Insert File.
5. Remove section break from the beginning of inserted doc2 (not from the end of doc1, as this breaks doc1's header).

While there may be a simpler method, the above worked for me (tested with simple documents with different margins and headers in Word 2010).